# javascript, Array.prototype.map(). index is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I don't know the reason of the error:

```
 ｛ (questionList.length > 0) && questionList.map((item,index)
          =>
          <View key={index} style={styles.oneMonthV}>
            <Text
                style={[styles.textTGray, styles.fontTSize, TEXT_STYLE, styles.fontTQuestion]}>{item.content}</Text>
            <View style={styles.VTags}>
              {item.optionsList.map((item1, index1) =>
                  <TouchableOpacity key={index1}
                                    onPress={this._onPressButton.bind(this, index1)}>
                    <View>
                      { (item1.selected) ? (<TagCell modeColor='red'
                                                     content={item1.content}></TagCell>) : (
                          <TagCell
                              content={item1.content}></TagCell>) }
                    </View>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
              ) }
            </View>
          </View>
          )｝
```

The error show  at

`<View key={index} style={styles.oneMonthV}>`  . Why index is undefined.

I type the code below in the `chrome` console is correct.

```
['xxx','xx','xxx','www'].map((item,index) => {        console.log(`index==${index}`);  console.log(`item==${item}`);
    return (
        item + 'hahaha' )});
```

result:

```
> index==0  
  item==xxx  
  index==1  
  item==xx  
  index==2  
  item==xxx  
  index==3  
  item==www  
(4) ["xxxhahaha", "xxhahaha", "xxxhahaha", "wwwhahaha"]
```

I think my code is correct. 
 Who knows the reason of this error?

---

As this error is too difficult.
I add more code of this question.

```
render() {
    const {questionList} = this.props;
    return (
        <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
          ｛ (questionList.length > 0) && questionList.map((item,index) => (
          <View key={index} style={styles.oneMonthV}>
            <Text
                style={[styles.textTGray, styles.fontTSize, TEXT_STYLE, styles.fontTQuestion]}>{item.content}</Text>
            <View style={styles.VTags}>
              {item.optionsList.map((item1, index1) => (
                      <TouchableOpacity key={index1}
                                        onPress={this._onPressButton.bind(this, index1)}>
                        <View>
                          { (item1.selected) ? (<TagCell modeColor='red'
                                                         content={item1.content}></TagCell>) : (
                              <TagCell
                                  content={item1.content}></TagCell>) }
                        </View>
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                  )
              ) }
            </View>
          </View>
          )
          )｝
        </ScrollView>
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: perhaps try putting `=>` on the same line as `(item,index)` - I know babel struggles otherwise

Comment: This in theory shouldn't even transpile with Babel...

Comment: couple of things. 
1 - place the  => at the same level as the (item, index).
2 - wrap your jsx in () as is a multiple jsx
3 - don't use index as key is terrible for reconciliation if you add or remove elements from the array.
4 - style props as an Array ?? never seen that one before

after fixing those things maybe it will be simpler to read. and maybe babel would not get confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few things going wrong, whenever you make use of arrow function, you should start with the body of the function on the same line. Also its a good practise to wrap it in `()`, also your check is unnecessary since if no element is present it wont map, however you must check for `undefined`. Also change `｛｝` to `{}`.

```
{questionList && questionList.map((item,index) => (
      <View key={index} style={styles.oneMonthV}>
        <Text
            style={[styles.textTGray, styles.fontTSize, TEXT_STYLE, styles.fontTQuestion]}>{item.content}</Text>
        <View style={styles.VTags}>
          {item.optionsList.map((item1, index1) => (
              <TouchableOpacity key={index1}
                                onPress={this._onPressButton.bind(this, index1)}>
                <View>
                  { (item1.selected) ? (<TagCell modeColor='red'
                                                 content={item1.content}></TagCell>) : (
                      <TagCell
                          content={item1.content}></TagCell>) }
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              )
          ) }
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  )}
```

Comment: @Shubham Khatri   "index is not defined"

Comment: @A.Lau Not necessary, it's just grouping after all. Makes it look cleaner IMO

Comment: Ok so I think there is another issue, ie. with the `｛` character before and after the map function, Use `{` and `}`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri    `｛｝`　＝＞`{}` is the another issue. Thank you very much. Please add this issue to your answer.

Comment: Added this to the answer :)